# dual boot windows 10 from a different pc's hdd

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, windows-xp, ssd

I had my old pc dual book windows xp and windows 8 
Windows xp was on different hard disk
WIndows 8 was on a ssd

Now I removed windows8 ssd, and istalled it on aanother machinw which already has win10 installed.

I boot but I dont see the dual boot message. Do  I need to reinstall it? Or there is a quick fix to make it load that windows 8 as dual boot on current machine.

Im out of space to try to make a fresh install

Answer (score 1):

The only way to try and transfer from an old machine to new is to use the [Sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview) tool:
If you do a fresh install, you have 3 options.

1. 1. Insert both hard drives and find which hard drive the system boots into.
   2. The OS which gets booted will be managing the bootloader for the system.
   3. Download EasyBCD, or something similar, of your choice if you can find it. Then install it on the main booted drive. [EasyBCD can be found here](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
2. Figure out what key will allow you to select the OS during boot... <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, etc. This will bring up the drives installed and allows a selection.
3. Manually select boot order in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Will the other windows boot correctly even if it was installed on another system?

Comment: @inrob Most likely it won't for two reasons: 1) Windows is very picky about drivers and stuff and not designed for portability (actually that isn't even allowed except with the Windows to Go feature) and 2) BIOS (legacy) boot and UEFI boot are very different; if it boots in one mode it won't in the other.

Comment: If you get the BIOS setup properly it may. You HAVE to Sysprep the machine using the /generalize switch before transferring it. Windows will then set itself back up on the new hardware. It can be a big pita to move to a completely new system, unfortunately. More than likely you will have to call Microsoft about activation. There is some more info on Sysprep here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview

Comment: Not worth if for me, id rather buy a cheap ssd than do all that